# Why doesn't knockoutjs run this computed function when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm working with Google Maps API and KnockoutJS, after creating the markers of the map I'm passing them, together with the animation(show infowindow and bounce marker) and the name of the location into an observableArray like so:

```
viewModel.addMarkersForKo(marker, venueName, doAnimation);
```

This (above) takes the marker, marker name (venueName) and the animation (a long list of combinations between showing infowindow for the marker passed, the content of the infowindow and marker icon animations etc)

```
addMarkersForKo: (aMarker, markerName, animation) => {
        let marker = {
            marker: aMarker,
            name: markerName,
            animation: animation
        };
        koViewModel.allMarkers().push(marker);
    }
```

This is where I'm taking the values and pushing them further inside the observableArray for Knockout.

```
let koViewModel = {
    allMarkers: ko.observableArray()
};

koViewModel.Query = ko.observable('');

koViewModel.Search = ko.computed( () => {
    let q = koViewModel.Query();
    return koViewModel.allMarkers().filter( 
        (i) => i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0
    )
});
```

Finally this is all that knockout is being bind to because before doing all of this I'm binding it like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(koViewModel);
```

And this (below) is my html binding:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: Query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="search" placeholder="Filter...">
<ul data-bind="foreach: Search">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: animation"></li>
</ul>
```

Everything works perfectly, so the rest of the code isn't necessary. It correctly filters through the list of markers and clicking on the list item pops up the correct marker and so-on!

The problem is that after loading the page, the list is empty, and it's only after I type a letter inside that it displays the list items...and If I for example press 'A' then 'Backspace' it will show all of the markers in the list.
I've tested this with console logging the result of that ko.computed, and it only runs after a key is being pressed, before I press a key it retuns undefined.
How do I get it to return the markers and compose the list items as soon as the page loads.

Comment: Are you certain the code isn't fired?  The foreach: binding should evaluate the Search observable, so if you set a breakpoint on the code in your chrome devtools, you should see it fired once. However, the initial evaluation of it might be empty because of the filter() action.  But the fact that something occurs when you type in a value meas the computed is being triggered by the observable Query.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`afterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding to execute it at the begining.

```
<input data-bind="textInput: Query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="search" placeholder="Filter...">
<ul data-bind="foreach: Search, afterRender: Search">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: animation"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, nothing's happening, and it doesn't help how KnockoutJs has little to no error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

`koViewModel.allMarkers().push(marker);`

is unwrapping your observableArray and then pushing the data into the underlying array directly (outside the knowledge of the depedency tracker). I'd suggest changing that to this:

`koViewModel.allMarkers.push(marker); // note, pushing on the observableArrray, not the unwraped, underlying array`